# Play audio on smartphone, received via bluetooth, from a SensorTile (STEVAL-STLKT01V1)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, stm32

I am making an app that can play audio received via bluetooth from a board with sensors including the microphone.
In the activity of the audio feature there are two buttons that will allow you to start playing audio in stream mode and stop playback. Unfortunately at the moment it does not work as I would like.
The problem is that audioSample is null, so I can not get into the onUpdate method and extract the audio from the sample.

Changes: listener change, adding a button to disable audio

Below the code relating to activity:

```
package com.st.BlueSTSDK.Example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Feature;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Features.FeatureAudioADPCM;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Features.FeatureAudioADPCMSync;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Manager;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Node;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Utils.BVAudioSyncManager;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Cesare on 09/06/2017.
 */

public class FeatureAudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     *   Node that will show the data
     */
    private Node mNode;

    /** fragment used for keep the connection open */
    private NodeContainerFragment mNodeContainer;

    //  Feature on which to apply the listener
    private FeatureAudioADPCM mAudio;

    // feature where we read the audio sync values
    private FeatureAudioADPCMSync mAudioSync;

    // The sampling rate
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;

    // raw audio
    private short audioSample[];

    // audio manager
    private static final int AUDIO_STREAM = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

    //  Audio track builder
    private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;

    //object containing the sync data needed in a ADPCM stream decoding
    private BVAudioSyncManager mBVAudioSyncManager = new BVAudioSyncManager();


    private final static String NODE_FRAGMENT =   FeatureAudioActivity.class.getCanonicalName() + "" +
        ".NODE_FRAGMENT";
    private final static String NODE_TAG = FeatureAudioActivity.class.getCanonicalName() + "" +
        ".NODE_TAG";



    /**
     * create an intent for start the activity that will log the information from the node
     *
     * @param c    context used for create the intent
     * @param node note that will be used by the activity
     * @return intent for start this activity
     */
    public static Intent getStartIntent(Context c, @NonNull Node node) {
        Intent i = new Intent(c, FeatureAudioActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(NODE_TAG, node.getTag());
        i.putExtras(NodeContainerFragment.prepareArguments(node));
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * listener for the audio feature, it will updates the audio values
     */
    public final Feature.FeatureListener mAudioListener = new Feature.FeatureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final Feature f, final Feature.Sample sample) {
            audioSample = FeatureAudioADPCM.getAudio(sample);
        }

    };

    /**
     * listener for the audioSync feature, it will update the synchronism values
     */
    public final Feature.FeatureListener mAudioSyncListener = new Feature.FeatureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Feature f, final Feature.Sample sample) {
            if(mBVAudioSyncManager!=null){
                mBVAudioSyncManager.setSyncParams(sample);
            }
        }
    };

/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
    private SeekBar mVolumeBar;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    private Button mPlayButton;
    private Button mStopButton;

    private ImageButton mMuteButton;
    private boolean mIsMute = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_audio);

        // find the node.
        String nodeTag = getIntent().getStringExtra(NODE_TAG);
        mNode = Manager.getSharedInstance().getNodeWithTag(nodeTag);


        List<Feature> listFeature = mNode.getFeatures();
        for (Feature f : listFeature) {
            if (f.isEnabled() && f.getName().equals("AudioFeature")) {

                mAudio=(FeatureAudioADPCM) f;

            }//if
            if (f.isEnabled() && f.getName().equals("AudioSyncFeature")) {

                mAudioSync=(FeatureAudioADPCMSync) f;

            }//if
        }//for


        //create/recover the NodeContainerFragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            mNodeContainer = new NodeContainerFragment();
            mNodeContainer.setArguments(i.getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(mNodeContainer, NODE_FRAGMENT).commit();
        } else {
            mNodeContainer = (NodeContainerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(NODE_FRAGMENT);
        }//if-else



        //builder audio track
        mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                FeatureAudioADPCM.AUDIO_PACKAGE_SIZE,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);





        mPlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        mMuteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);

//        //start speaker phone
//        AudioManager audioManager =  (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
//        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);


        //  When the play button is pressed
        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mAudioTrack.play();

                /*Write audio data for playback
              @param short : The array that contains the data for playback
              @param int: offset in rawAudio where playback data begins
              @param int: The number of shorts to read in rawAudio after the offset
                */
                mAudioTrack.write(audioSample,0,audioSample.length);
            }
        });

        //When the stop button is pressed
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mAudioTrack.stop();
            }
        });

        //When the mute button is pressed
        mMuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeState();
            }
            boolean changeState(){
                mIsMute=!mIsMute;
                if(mIsMute)
                    muteAudio();
                else
                    unMuteAudio();
                return mIsMute;
            }
            private void muteAudio(){
                  mMuteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_black_32dp);
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,0,0);
                mVolumeBar.setEnabled(false);
            }

            private void unMuteAudio(){
                mMuteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_black_32dp);
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,mVolumeBar.getProgress(),0);
            mVolumeBar.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });


        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        initControls();


        mAudioSync.addFeatureListener(mAudioSyncListener);
        mAudio.setAudioSyncManager(mBVAudioSyncManager);
        mAudio.addFeatureListener(mAudioListener);
        mNode.enableNotification(mAudio);



    }

    //   Volume control from SeekBar
    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            mVolumeBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeValue);
            mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mVolumeBar.setMax(mAudioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            mVolumeBar.setProgress(mAudioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


            mVolumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
                {
                    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * if we have to leave this activity, we force to keep the connection open, since we go back
     * in the {@link FeatureListActivity}
     */
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        mNodeContainer.keepConnectionOpen(true);
        super.onBackPressed();
     }//onBackPressed


}
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhKKC.jpg

Comment: What is the configuration? The SensorTile is powered by the battery, paired to the Android phone? Did you have to do any additional programming of the SensorTile? I am trying to do the same thing on iOS.

Comment: The SensorTile is currently on the cradle expansion board used to rogram it. Find the information here: [link]http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/solution-evaluation-tools/sensor-solution-eval-boards/steval-stlkt01v1.html. Download the user manual. The SensorTile has the BLUMYCROSYSTEM2 firmware: [link]http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/bluemicrosystem2.html.html. In the BlueST-SDK there is a class where disabling the features you do not use. It is in Utils, the name is BLENodeDefines.@sAguinaga

Comment: I've downloaded the BlueSTSDK_iOS GitHub repo and it does have a `Util/BlueSTSDKBleNodeDefines.h` file I will try to do the same thing you are doing: pair my module with an iPhone, initiate audio recording (short duration, for example say 4 or 5 seconds), & play it back on the host device.

Comment: I know I am not adding to a solution, yet, but I hope you don't mind. Here is a link to my [hardware configuration](https://www.flickr.com/photos/83956760@N00/shares/Yt6S10)

Comment: Correction, the CradleExpansionBoard is connected to USB port for power and **not** via the NUCLEO board.

Comment: on your BlueSTSDKExample app>>Feature List table-view, do you have more than 7 items? The last on the list for me is "Mic Level" but all of the features are included/imported into the file: BlueSTSDKBleNodeDefines what else are you doing to enable AudioPCM?

Comment: I also had the same problem. The AudioADPCM feature was not on the list. I solved by updating the firmware BLUEMICROSYSTEM2 to version 2.2.0. In the previous firmware there was no BlueVoice library.

Comment: @sAguinaga To play audio in real time, you must before record it using an AudioBuffer object?

Comment: Ah, got it. btw: ST BlueMS app from Android/iOS stores require that the user requests an osxAudioBV (BlueVoice) license to enable audio over-the-air. Is that not required when you use AudioADPCM after upgrading to version 2.2.0? And yes, I'd like to save the audio signal in some CoreAudio format for replay and signal analysis offline.

Comment: No, once you have upgraded your firmware, you must apply for all licenses, including the BlueVoice license. The BLIUEMICROSYSTEM2 firmware user manual on page 45 explains how to do it.

@sAguinaga do you think that you can play audio in real time without recording it, so do not use an AudioBuffer object?

Comment: The ST BlueMS app (android or ios) as-is plays real-time audio, but they don't offer a way to store the audio for later access. [GiovanniVisentini](https://github.com/GiovanniVisentini) says that calling FeatureAudioADPCM.getLinearPCMAudio (in iOS) will return the PCM audio that you can store on a wav file, and yes most likely by creating an AudioBuffer object. Send email and I can go into more detail. Lastly, how did you upgrade the firmware --over-the-air or using the Nucleo board?

Comment: Actually, just look at his comment to my question on [GitHub](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics-CentralLabs/BlueSTSDK_iOS/issues/1)

Comment: Ok, my mail is cesarevecchie@hotmail.it.
I've updated the firmware through the BlueMS app, over-the-air

Comment: I do not understand what it says: "You can not use the BlueSTSDKExample app since the data from the 2 features must be combined to properly decode the audio stream, so you have to edit it." ? I've created the activities and layouts in the BLUESTSDExample module. It's wrong

Comment: I've created the activities and layouts in the BLUESTSDExample module. It's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the write method inside the onUpdate method. This allows you to write new audio each time we have a new sample. Adding onResume and onUpdate methods in which we respectively enable and disable the mAudio and mAudioSync notifications. Changes to setOnClickListener methods for play and stop bottoms.

```
package com.st.BlueSTSDK.Example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Feature;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Features.FeatureAudioADPCM;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Features.FeatureAudioADPCMSync;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Manager;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Node;
import com.st.BlueSTSDK.Utils.BVAudioSyncManager;

import java.util.List;


public class FeatureAudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 *   Node that will show the data
 */
private Node mNode;

/** fragment used for keep the connection open */
private NodeContainerFragment mNodeContainer;

//  Feature on which to apply the listener
private FeatureAudioADPCM mAudio;

// feature where we read the audio sync values
private FeatureAudioADPCMSync mAudioSync;

// The sampling rate
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;

// audio manager
private static final int AUDIO_STREAM = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

//  Audio track builder
private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;

//object containing the sync data needed in a ADPCM stream decoding
private BVAudioSyncManager mBVAudioSyncManager = new BVAudioSyncManager();


private final static String NODE_FRAGMENT =   FeatureAudioActivity.class.getCanonicalName() + "" +
        ".NODE_FRAGMENT";
private final static String NODE_TAG = FeatureAudioActivity.class.getCanonicalName() + "" +
        ".NODE_TAG";



/**
 * create an intent for start the activity that will log the information from the node
 *
 * @param c    context used for create the intent
 * @param node note that will be used by the activity
 * @return intent for start this activity
 */
public static Intent getStartIntent(Context c, @NonNull Node node) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, FeatureAudioActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(NODE_TAG, node.getTag());
    i.putExtras(NodeContainerFragment.prepareArguments(node));
    return i;
}

/**
 * listener for the audio feature, it will updates the audio values
 */
public final Feature.FeatureListener mAudioListener = new Feature.FeatureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final Feature f, final Feature.Sample sample) {
        short audioSample[] = FeatureAudioADPCM.getAudio(sample);

          /*Write audio data for playback
          @param short : The array that contains the data for playback
          @param int: offset in rawAudio where playback data begins
          @param int: The number of shorts to read in rawAudio after the offset
            */
        mAudioTrack.write(audioSample,0,audioSample.length);
    }

};

/**
 * listener for the audioSync feature, it will update the synchronism values
 */
public final Feature.FeatureListener mAudioSyncListener = new Feature.FeatureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Feature f, final Feature.Sample sample) {
        if(mBVAudioSyncManager!=null){
            mBVAudioSyncManager.setSyncParams(sample);
        }
    }
};

/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
private SeekBar mVolumeBar;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

private Button mPlayButton;
private Button mStopButton;

private ImageButton mMuteButton;
private boolean mIsMute = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_audio);

    // find the node.
    String nodeTag = getIntent().getStringExtra(NODE_TAG);
    mNode = Manager.getSharedInstance().getNodeWithTag(nodeTag);


    List<Feature> listFeature = mNode.getFeatures();
    for (Feature f : listFeature) {
        if (f.isEnabled() && f.getName().equals("AudioFeature")) {

            mAudio=(FeatureAudioADPCM) f;

        }//if
        if (f.isEnabled() && f.getName().equals("AudioSyncFeature")) {

            mAudioSync=(FeatureAudioADPCMSync) f;

        }//if
    }//for


    //create/recover the NodeContainerFragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        mNodeContainer = new NodeContainerFragment();
        mNodeContainer.setArguments(i.getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(mNodeContainer, NODE_FRAGMENT).commit();
    } else {
        mNodeContainer = (NodeContainerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(NODE_FRAGMENT);
    }//if-else



    //builder audio track
    mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            FeatureAudioADPCM.AUDIO_PACKAGE_SIZE,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);



    mPlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    mMuteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);



    //  When the play button is pressed
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!mIsMute){
                mAudioTrack.play();
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,mVolumeBar.getProgress(),0);
            }

        }
    });

    //When the stop button is pressed
    mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            stopAudioTrack();
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,0,0);

        }
    });

    //When the mute button is pressed
    mMuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeState();
        }
        boolean changeState(){
            mIsMute=!mIsMute;
            if(mIsMute)
                muteAudio();
            else
                unMuteAudio();
            return mIsMute;
        }
        private void muteAudio(){
            mMuteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_black_32dp);
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,0,0);
            mVolumeBar.setEnabled(false);
        }

        private void unMuteAudio(){
            mMuteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_black_32dp);
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AUDIO_STREAM,mVolumeBar.getProgress(),0);
            mVolumeBar.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    //enable control volume
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    initControls();


}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // enable needed notification
    if(mAudio!=null && mAudioSync!=null) {
        mAudio.addFeatureListener(mAudioListener);
        mBVAudioSyncManager.reinitResetFlag();
        mAudio.setAudioSyncManager(mBVAudioSyncManager);
        mNode.enableNotification(mAudio);
        mAudioSync.addFeatureListener(mAudioSyncListener);
        mNode.enableNotification(mAudioSync);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    // disable needed notification
    if(mAudio!=null) {
        mAudio.removeFeatureListener(mAudioListener);
        mNode.disableNotification(mAudio);
    }
    if(mAudioSync!=null) {
        mAudioSync.removeFeatureListener(mAudioSyncListener);
        mNode.disableNotification(mAudioSync);
    }
}



private void stopAudioTrack(){
    synchronized(this) {
        mAudioTrack.pause();
        mAudioTrack.flush();
    }
}



//   Volume control from SeekBar
private void initControls()
{
    try
    {
        mVolumeBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeValue);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mVolumeBar.setMax(mAudioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        mVolumeBar.setProgress(mAudioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


        mVolumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
            {
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * if we have to leave this activity, we force to keep the connection open, since we go back
 * in the {@link FeatureListActivity}
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mNodeContainer.keepConnectionOpen(true);
    super.onBackPressed();
}//onBackPressed
```

}

Comment: did you try different sampling rates (16 upto 44KHz)?